# (node:207476) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1):

Tags: contract-deployment, crowdsale, truffle-deployment

Here is where error appears:

```
> Using network 'ropsten'.
> 
> Running migration: 1_initial_migration.js   
Deploying Migrations...  
> ... 0x53526c506e2e43ee2be615375a11b8507a1e50ccc7a70e7ee5bd4fc745ec6f96
> Migrations: 0xe26a476c08385fccaf0aacb5b08126ef9d134965 
Saving
> successful migration to network...   ...
> 0x72b8a0c6d09346ac205582041fbdc3a6853eab5523fd9c2de156ea0fc0cad1c5
> Saving artifacts... Running migration: 2_deploy_contracts.js Saving
> successful migration to network...   
Deploying XYZCoinCrowdsale...  
> ... 0x41d927717c89355dd0faa95cd6bf9421ff01c4c8c35c033d31f31e7d923b52e7
> ... 0x9c09d068e7d39de04d60546f167ba1c3b96544deba1e8c57389610e6106dcb2b
> Saving artifacts... (node:207476) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning:
> Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): Error: The contract
> code couldn't be stored, please check your gas amount. 
>(node:207476)
> [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are
> deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled
> will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Tried everything mentioned on various questions here, none of them worked.
I attempt to replica the guide here, https://blog.zeppelin.solutions/how-to-create-token-and-initial-coin-offering-contracts-using-truffle-openzeppelin-1b7a5dae99b6 except on ropsten using hdwallet-provider.

I edited   xyzcoincrowdsale.sol(removed line // Crowdsale(_startTime, _endTime, _rate, _wallet) which was in the gustavocoincrowdsale.sol because it gave an error.)

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.13;

import './xyzcoin.sol';
import 'zeppelin-solidity/contracts/crowdsale/Crowdsale.sol';


contract XYZCoinCrowdsale is Crowdsale {

  function XYZCoinCrowdsale(uint256 _startTime, uint256 _endTime, uint256 _rate, address _wallet) 
   // Crowdsale(_startTime, _endTime, _rate, _wallet)
    {          
  }

  // creates the token to be sold.
  // override this method to have crowdsale of a specific MintableToken token.
  function createTokenContract() internal returns (MintableToken) {
    return new XYZCoin();
  }

}
```

My truffle.cfg looks like this:

```
require('dotenv').config();
const Web3 = require('web3');
const web3 = new Web3();
const Wallet = require('ethereumjs-wallet');

var HDWalletProvider = require("truffle-hdwallet-provider");
var infura_apikey = "Infura API HERE";
var mnemonic = "12 words here";

module.exports = {
  networks: {
    development: {
      host: "localhost",
      port: 8545,
      network_id: "*", // Match any network id
      from: '0x00000000000000000000000000000000000'
    },
    ropsten: {
      //host: "localhost",
      //port: 8545,
      //nonce: 20,
      provider: new HDWalletProvider(mnemonic, "https://ropsten.infura.io/"+infura_apikey),
      network_id: 3,
      gas: 472388,
      gasPrice: 100000000000
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: Can you share your deploy script? From the error it appears the issue is there.

Comment: const XYZCrowdsale = artifacts.require("XYZCrowdsale")
module.exports = function(deployer, network, accounts) {
  web3.eth.getBlockNumber((e, block) => {
//web3.eth.getBlock(web3.eth.blockNumber, (e, block) => {
    if(!e) {
      const startTime = block.timestamp + 120 //one second in the future
      const endTime = startTime + (86400 * 20) // 20 days
      const rate = new web3.BigNumber(1000)
      const wallet = accounts[0]
      deployer.deploy(XYZCrowdsale, startTime, endTime, rate, wallet)
      
    }
  })
};

Answer (score 1):

This should work if you want to retrieve information from the latest block before deploying the new contract.

```
const XYZCrowdsale = artifacts.require("XYZCrowdsale")

module.exports = function(deployer, network, accounts) {
  deployer.then(() => {
    web3.eth.getBlock('latest', (e, block) => {
      if(!e) {
        const startTime = block.timestamp + 120 //one second in the future
        const endTime = startTime + (86400 * 20) // 20 days
        const rate = new web3.BigNumber(1000)
        const wallet = accounts[0]
        deployer.deploy(XYZCrowdsale, startTime, endTime, rate, wallet)
      }
    })
  })
};
```

Comment: Figured everything out finally. This code worked and had to adjust gas price at the end.